# How to code a strcat function that works with two dynamic arrays

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, dynamic-arrays, c-strings, strcat

As we know, the strcat function concatinates one c-string onto another to make one big c-string containing two others.

My question is how to make a `strcat` function that works with two dynamically allocated arrays.

The desired `strcat` function should be able to work for any sized myStr1 and myStr2

```
//dynamic c-string array 1
char* myStr1 = new char [26];
strcpy(myStr1, "The dog on the farm goes ");

//dynamic c-string array 2
char* myStr2 = new char [6];
strcpy(myStr2, "bark.");

//desired function
strcat(myStr1,myStr2);
cout<<myStr1; //would output 'The dog on the farm goes bark.'
```

This is as far as I was able to get on my own:

```
//*& indicates that the dynamic c-string str1 is passed by reference
void strcat(char*& str1, char* str2) 
{
    int size1 = strlen(str1);
    int size2 = strlen(str2);
    //unknown code
    //str1 = new char [size1+size2]; //Would wipe out str1's original contents
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can carry on like this; but don't assign the new space to `str1` until after you have copied the old string out of `str1` and freed the old space

Comment: I'm bewildered as to why `std::string` isn't used instead of this thing you posted that makes my eyes bleed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first to understand better how pointers work. Your code for example:

```
char* myStr1 = new char [25];
myStr1 = "The dog on the farm goes ";
```

first allocates 25 characters, then ignores the pointer to that allocated area (the technical term is "leaks it") and sets `myStr1` to point to a string literal.

That code should have used `strcpy` instead to copy from the string literal into the allocated area. Except that the string is 25 characters so you will need to allocate space for at least 26 as one is needed for the ASCII `NUL` terminator (`0x00`).

Correct code for that part should have been:

```
char* myStr1 = new char [26]; // One more than the actual string length
strcpy(myStr1, "The dog on the farm goes ");
```

To do the concatenation of C strings the algorithm could be:

1. measure the lengths `n1` and `n2` of the two strings (with `strlen`)
2. allocate `n1+n2+1` charaters for the destination buffer (`+1` is needed for the C string terminator)
3. `strcpy` the first string at the start of the buffer
4. `strcat` the second string to the buffer (*)
5. `delete[]` the memory for the original string buffers **if they are not needed** (if this is the right thing to do or not depends on who is the "owner" of the strings... this part is tricky as the C string interface doesn't specify that).

(*) This is not the most efficient way. `strcat` will go through all the characters of the string to find where it ends, but you already know that the first string length is `n1` and the concatenation could be done instead with `strcpy` too by choosing the correct start as `buffer+n1`. Even better instead of `strcpy` you could use `memcpy` everywhere if you know the count as `strcpy` will have to check each character for being the `NUL` terminator. Before getting into this kind of optimization however you should understand clearly how things work... only once the string concatenation code is correct and for you **totally obvious** you are authorized to even start thinking about optimization.

PS: Once you get all this correct and working and efficient you will appreciate how much of a simplification is to use `std::string` objects instead, where all this convoluted code becomes just `s1+s2`.

Comment: Took me a while to understand why strcpy() is the way to assign things on dynamic char arrays. Its a silly mistake assigning it like myStr1 = "bark." I'm pretty sure this will help me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You allocate memory and make your pointers point to that memory. Then you *overwrite* the pointers, making them point somewhere else. The assignment of e.g. `myStr1` causes the variable to point to the string literal instead of the memory you allocated. You need to *copy* the strings into the memory you have allocated.

Of course, that copying will lead to another problem, as you seem to forget that C-strings need an extra character for the terminator. So a C-string with 5 characters needs space for *six* characters.

---

As for your concatenation function, you need to do copying here too. Allocate enough space for both strings *plus* a single terminator character. Then copy the first string into the beginning of the new memory, and copy the second string into the end.

Also you need a temporary pointer variable for the memory you allocate, as you otherwise "would wipe out str1's original contents" (not strictly true, you just make `str1` point somewhere else, losing the original pointer).